# replace a substring inside a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop, google-search-api

I am running an API query like this. Instead of "montratec" here `q=montratec`, I want to use various different words that I have stored in a list. I want to run this inside a for loop by replacing the word `montratec` with different elements in the list `names`. How can I achieve this?

```
url = "https://google-search3.p.rapidapi.com/api/v1/crawl/q=montratec%20AND%20(katalog%20OR%20catalog%20OR%20brosch%C3%BCre%20OR%20brochure)%20AND%20filetype=pdf&num=5"
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
```

```
for i in names:
    url = "https://google-search3.p.rapidapi.com/api/v1/crawl/q=montratec%20AND%20(katalog%20OR%20catalog%20OR%20brosch%C3%BCre%20OR%20brochure)%20AND%20filetype=pdf&num=5"
```

Comment: See `str.replace()` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the below (use "f" string)

```
for name in names:
    url = f"https://google-search3.p.rapidapi.com/api/v1/crawl/q={name}%20AND%20(katalog%20OR%20catalog%20OR%20brosch%C3%BCre%20OR%20brochure)%20AND%20filetype=pdf&num=5"
```